# OpenLayers OSM performance issue on mobile browser

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, openlayers

I face a problem with slowdowns when I try to drag the map on my Samsung Galaxy A5 Chrome browser. Map is rendered by OpenLayers 4.6.5 version. So I've made a Leaflet version with the same source link and... everything works just great, there is no slowdowns and other holds... You can check it by yourself on your mobile.

- Here is the OL link: http://178.208.82.80:5938/testMap
- Here is the Leaflet link: http://178.208.82.80:5938/testMap2

**Here is the OL version code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TileHosting</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=fetch,Promise"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.5/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.klokantech.com/ol-mapbox-style/v2.11.0-pre/olms.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.5/ol.css">
    <style>
        #map {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <p><a href="https://carto.com/" target="_blank">© CARTO</a> <a href="http://www.openmaptiles.org/" target="_blank">© OpenMapTiles</a> <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/about/" target="_blank">© OpenStreetMap contributors</a></p>
    <script>
        var layers = [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                url: 'https://tile-a.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                crossOrigin: null
            })
        })
];

var view = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([36.587147, 50.598299], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 10,
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 18
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new ol.control.ScaleLine({
            units: 'degrees'
            })
    ]),
    layers: layers,
    target: 'map',
    view: view
});

</script>
</body>
```

Here is the Leaflet version code:

```
<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />

<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Leaflet Example</h1>
    <p>Here's a map of the countries I've either lived in or travelled through for a month or more.

    <div id="map" style="height: 440px; border: 1px solid #AAA;"></div>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='maps/markers.json'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='maps/leaf-demo.js'></script>

    <script>
        var map = L.map( 'map', {
            center: [50.598299, 36.587147],
            minZoom: 2,
            zoom: 10
        });

    L.tileLayer( 'https://tile-a.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a                                                 href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    subdomains: ['a','b','c']
    }).addTo( map );

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

What is this? Is it means that OL is very unproductive? Or it has to be some special setting?

Comment: try with Android via the "More > Desktop version" is there an improvement?

Comment: @Mapperz hm... I can't find this kind of setting in my mobile chrome browser.

Comment: @Mapperz it feels like in Opera it works a little bit faster

Comment: for chrome https://www.techbout.com/request-desktop-version-website-android-phone-17720/

Comment: @Mapperz Thank you for this hint, but if it helped then quite a bit... still Leaflet version is much smoother pans than OpenLayers.